# Css flex aligments issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got stuck stacking the elements inside the flex. I want these arrows to be aligned within this square as in the design image.

[image]

This is how it looks is code. It's examle of html and css file.

```css
// This is CSS code picture were missed

.external-login {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 21px 30.5px 21px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    border: solid 1px #dee2eb;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    h3 {
        color: #525458;
    }
}
    
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.google-image {
    background-image: url($url);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.facebook-image {
    background-image: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/145/145802.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.carat-image {
    background-image: url($url);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is HTML code -->

 <div class="row external-login">
            <div class="google-image"></div>
            <h3>Continue with Google</h3>
            <div class="carat-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row external-login">
            <div class="facebook-image"></div>
            <h3>Continue with Facebook</h3>
            <div class="carat-image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

These pictures were missed in code snippet below.

**EDIT**

I've changed

```
 justify-content: flex-start;
```

to

```
 justify-content: space-between;
```

and got like this, not bad but text is not align.

[image]

Comment: The images are not included because you are using something other than pure CSS in the snippet (e.g. `$url`). Please include actual absolute values so we can fully reproduce your error. You can use placeholder/dummy images of the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height: fit-content;` and `align-self: center` to your `.carat-image` class.

Comment: @jordanlatimer the same thing it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center the elements which are wrapped by flex div, try `align-items: center`. Also, to align a particular child to the right, Use `justify-self: end`. Use `flex-direction: column` to place the elements inline. To fix the width, add `flex: 1` to `h3`

```css
// This is CSS code picture were missed

.external-login {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 21px 30.5px 21px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    border: solid 1px #dee2eb;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    h3 {
        color: #525458;
    }
}
    
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
 
.google-image {
    background-image: url($url);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.facebook-image {
    background-image: url($url);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.carat-image {
    background-image: url($url);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: right;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    height: fit-content;
    
}

   h3 {
 flex:1
}

.content .row:nth-child(2) .carat-image {
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.content .row:nth-child(3) .carat-image {
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is HTML code -->

 <div class="row external-login"> 
   
     <div class="google-image">.</div>
      <h3>Continue with Google</h3>
  
    <div class="carat-image"> ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row external-login">
  
     <div class="facebook-image"></div>
      <h3>Continue with Facebook</h3>. 
      <div class="carat-image">></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so for your suggestion but I use row class in another places in html so when I change this it's "breaking style" on another places, but If I put it in external login class the same thing..

Comment: I have edited the code. You can try with the new one

Answer (score 0):

Simple change will fix the issue. add

> height: fit-content
>
> align-self: center

```
.carat-image {
  background-image: url($url);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
}
```